# Showing input value in the url link (ReactJs Laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I created laravel project with the reactjs framework and I'm new for this framework. I have problem and why It happens every time i submit the form.

[image: Problem]

**Goal:** users can register through online

**Problem:**

1. Why it happens when i submit the button the input value of user shown in the url link?
2. The data that I input is not inserted to the database.

Code:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

        f_name:'',
        l_name:'',
        m_name:'',
        email:'',
        home_num:'',
        contact_num:'',
        Job_name:[],
        employ_status:'',
        employ_relocate:'',
        employ_start_date:'',
        employ_file:''


    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handle_fname = this.handle_fname.bind(this);   
    this.handle_lname = this.handle_lname.bind(this);
    this.handle_mname = this.handle_mname.bind(this); 
    this.handle_email = this.handle_email.bind(this);
    this.handle_homenum = this.handle_homenum.bind(this);
    this.handle_contactnum = this.handle_contactnum.bind(this); 
    this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_status.bind(this);
    this.handle_employ_relocate = this.handle_employ_relocate.bind(this);
    this.handle_employ_start_date = this.handle_employ_start_date.bind(this);
    this.handle_employ_file = this.handle_employ_file.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get('/api/online_application_job_title/' +id).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            Job_name:response.data
        })
    })
}



    handleSubmit(e)
{
    const data = {
        firstname: this.state.f_name,
        lastname : this.state.l_name,
        middlename : this.state.m_name,
        email : this.state.email,
        home_number : this.state.home_num,
        contact_num : this.state.contact_num,
        job : this.state.Job_name[0].position_name,
        employ_status : this.state.employ_status,
        employ_relocate : this.state.employ_relocate,
        employ_start_date : this.state.employ_start_date,
        employ_file : this.state.employ_file

    }



    axios.post('/api/save_application',data).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

}

handle_fname(e)
    {
        this.setState({
            f_name:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handle_lname(e){
        this.setState({
            l_name:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handle_mname(e){
        this.setState({
            m_name:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handle_email(e){
        this.setState({
            email:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handle_homenum(e){
        this.setState({
            home_num:e.target.value
        })
    }
    handle_contactnum(e){
        this.setState({
            contact_num:e.target.value
        })
    }
    handle_employ_status(e){
        this.setState({
            employ_status:e.target.value
        });
    }
    handle_employ_relocate(e){
        this.setState({
            employ_relocate:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handle_employ_start_date(e){
        this.setState({
            employ_start_date:e.target.value,
        })
    }

    handle_employ_file(e){

        this.setState({
            employ_file: e.target.files[0].extension
        })


    }
renderName() {
    return (
        this.state.Job_name.map(name => (
            <input placeholder="" value={name.position_name} type="text" className="form-control"/>
        ))
    )
}





render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Online Application</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="container">
                    <h5><b>Personal Info</b></h5>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="First Name*"
                            value={this.state.f_name}
                            onChange={this.handle_fname}
                            className="form-control"/>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="Last Name*"
                            value={this.state.l_name} 
                            onChange={this.handle_lname}
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="Middle Name*"
                            value={this.state.m_name} 
                            onChange={this.handle_mname} 
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="Email Address*" 
                            type="email"
                            value={this.state.email} 
                            onChange={this.handle_email} 
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="Home Number*" 
                            type="number"
                            value={this.state.home_num} 
                            onChange={this.handle_homenum} 
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            placeholder="Contact Number*" 
                            type="number"
                            value={this.state.contact_num} 
                            onChange={this.handle_contactnum} 
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <h5><b>Employment Application</b></h5>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <p>Position Applying For</p>
                            {this.renderName()}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <p>1. What is your current employment status?</p>
                            <div className="form-check-inline">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    className="form-check-input"  
                                    name="employmentstatus"
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_status} 
                                    defaultChecked={false}
                                    value="Unemployed"/>Unemployed
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check-inline">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    name="employmentstatus"
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_status}  
                                    defaultChecked={false}
                                    value="Employed"/>Employed
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check-inline disabled">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    name="employmentstatus"
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_status} 
                                    defaultChecked={false} 
                                    value="Self-Employed"/>Self-Employed
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check-inline disabled">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    name="employmentstatus" 
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_status}
                                    defaultChecked={false}  
                                    value="Student"/>Student
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <p>2. Are you willing to relocate?</p>
                            <div className="form-check-inline">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" 
                                    name="relocate"
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_relocate} 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    value="Yes"/>Yes
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check-inline">
                                <label className="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" 
                                    name="relocate" 
                                    onChange={this.handle_employ_relocate} 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    value="No"/>No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <p>3. When is your available start date?</p>
                            <input 
                            name="startdate"
                            type="date"
                            onChange={this.handle_employ_start_date}
                            value={this.state.employ_start_date}  
                            required=""
                            className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <p>4. Kindly attach a copy of your resume (PDF,docx files only).</p>
                            <div className="custom-file">
                                <input 
                                type="file" 
                                name="file"
                                accept="application/msword,application/pdf"
                                onChange={this.handle_employ_file}
                                className="custom-file-input" 
                                id="inputGroupFile04"/>
                                <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                            className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-large form-control col-md-5"  
                            type="submit" 
                            value="Send Application"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


        </div>
    )
}
```

Controller:

```
public function save_application(Request $request)
{
    $firstname = $request->get('firstname');
    $lastname = $request->get('lastname');
    $middlename = $request->get('middlename');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $home_number = $request->get('home_number');
    $contact_num = $request->get('contact_num');
    $job = $request->get('job');
    $employ_status = $request->get('employ_status');
    $employ_relocate = $request->get('employ_relocate');
    $employ_start_date = $request->get('employ_start_date');
    $employ_file = $request->get('employ_file');

    $now = new DateTime();

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO onlineapplication 
    (position_name,firstname,middlename,lastname,email,homenumber,phonenumber,employmentstatus,relocate,starting_date,destination,file_img_name,Status) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[

        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $middlename,
        $email,
        $home_number,
        $contact_num,
        $job,
        $employ_status,
        $employ_relocate,
        $employ_start_date,
        $employ_file

    ]);


    return response()->json('Successfully inserted');


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When form tag is used, the submit will trigger the default behaviour that is based on the method provided and the action url. 
as in your example you are handling the data explicitly you should prevent the default behaviour. 
add the below code in handle submit

```
handleSubmit(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 ...
 ...
}
```

this will prevent the default behaviour.

Improvement for state update:
you don't need individual functions to update the input value to state this can be combined in one function.
to combine, provide the input name same as state name.

```
this.state ={
 "f_name": '',
 "l_name": '',
 ...
}



<input name="f_name" ... onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
<input name="l_name" .. onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

handleInputChange(e){
  let target = e.target;
  let name = target.name;
  let value = target.value

  this.setState({[name]: value})
}
```

for more info refer this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs).

Answer (score 0):

First, I just want to introduce to you to the *arrow function* in JavaScript (ES6). Declaring private methods like this:

```
handle_fname = (e) =>
{
    this.setState({
        f_name:e.target.value,
    })
}
```

will save you time from unnecessary binding in the constructor.

Regarding your question, you missed to show the content of your `this.handleSubmit()`. Without this, I can assume that the form submit fired a `get` call since you failed to put `method` attribute in your `<form/>` tag, and without indicating your method attribute will result to default get method. Get method when used, data submitted will be visible in the page address field of your browser.

**EDIT**

You already added your `handleSubmit()` in your question, and it looks okay. If data is still shown in the address field of your browser, try adding `method="post"` in your form tag like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="post">
```

Comment: Giving me Page Expired